# How to access enum from swift to Objective C

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have created `enum` in swift. I want to set value to `enum` in objective C. I am unable to get `enum` value in Objective C. Gratitude for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Just mark the enum by `@objc` like this:

```
@objc enum FitMode: Int {
    case Clip, Crop, Scale
}
```

Comment: Thanks dude for reply :), I have created variable for enum in Swift, I am unable to access enum variable from swift class into objective C class. So I am sending enum type (like FitMode.Clip) to swift function from objective C class. it works now :). Is there any better solution?